# How to make function to be invoked only once after rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How to make extraFunc function to be invoked only once after rendering, because when you click on counter that function automatically is invoked?
Thank you in advance.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
 
export const ProfilerCheckerApp = () => {
    const [counterValue, setCounterValue] = useState(0);
 
    const increase = () => setCounterValue(counterValue + 1);
    const decrease = () => setCounterValue(counterValue - 1);
 
    return (
        <>
            <Counter increase={increase} decrease={decrease} value={counterValue}/>
        </>
    )
}
 
const extraFunc = (value) => {
    console.log("ex func works");
    return "value is: " + value;
}
 
const Counter = ({increase = f => f, decrease = f => f, value = 0}) => {
 
    let my_value = extraFunc(value);
 
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
            <span style={{padding: "10px"}}>{my_value}</span>
            <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: With regards to: *"...because when you click on counter that function automatically is invoked..."*. That's because `<Counter/>` is not only rendered once, but everytime it's props or state changes (props here). Given your code this happens everytime `<ProfilerCheckerApp />` is rendered. Again because it's props or state changes (state here).

Comment: Given your comments on the answers below, please extend your question to include an explanation why you want `extraFunc` to run only once and that it currently is just a placeholder. Preferably while including some code that shows what the actual function would look like. That said, seeing what you wrote in your comments, it doesn't make much sense to have a function *run only once* yet still depend on a changing value.

Comment: My **extra Func** function is placeholder. You are right. There is no sense to invoke it. I  just want to have the skill of invoking functions once after rendering.

Comment: Well then you have your answer, the function is already executed exactly once **per** render, though the component get's rendered multiple times. If this is a learning project then you should invest some time in learning the proper *nomenclature*. For it seems, what you're after is actually to call the function only for the *initial* render. For that you would use `useEffect` as described in the answers below.

Comment: I used useEffect with no values in the dependency array, but I got a warning like this: `: 'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'value'. Either include it or remove the dependency array` . When I do how the warning said, the app doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: Yeah, and as @SinanYaman pointed out, it makes no sense. Think about it, you want a function that: - Runs exactly once - but also consumes an ever changing value. In your code you have `let my_value = extraFunc(value);` this call clearly **depends** on the current value of `value`, so it must be a dependency of `useEffect`. And as a asked in my second comment, please add a better explanation with regards to what you actually want to do here. Currently nobody can help you because you're just repeating the same two things: "Only once" and "Tried but doesn't work as expected".

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming what you meant by "function automatically invoking" is when you click on a button, you get prompted with the console.log "ex func works". Actually, that is the *intended* behaviour, because every time a React component's state gets updated (in this case, *value* changes because you clicked the + or - button)  will be **re-rendered** and extraFunc() will be called again from this line.

```
let my_value = extraFunc(value);
```

Instead of passing in the extraFunc() and assigning its value into the my_value variable, you can skip all those and directly render the text AND the value into the Counter component.

My way to do this would be to remove the **extraFunc()** entirely. Instead, I would just interpolate the text "VALUE IS" directly into your span.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const ProfilerCheckerApp = () => {
  const [counterValue, setCounterValue] = useState(0);

  const increase = () => setCounterValue(counterValue + 1);
  const decrease = () => setCounterValue(counterValue - 1);

  return (
    <>
      <Counter increase={increase} decrease={decrease} value={counterValue} />
    </>
  );
};

const Counter = ({ increase, decrease, value }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
      <span style={{ padding: "10px" }}>VALUE IS: {value}</span>
      <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also I refactored your props to make it look a little nicer. Instead of doing

```
const Counter = ({increase = f => f, decrease = f => f, value = 0}) => {
```

You can just go ahead and do this

```
const Counter = ({increase, decrease, value}) => {
```

This is much much readable, and it's what's actually the common convention. App still works as intended you can try and copy paste this entire block.

Should you need any more indepth explanation feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but i did the function invoking intentionally in component to simulate situation where i would use useMemo or useCallback.

Comment: I tried to implement useMemo or useCallback, but it did not work out. I decided to go another way of using useEffect with empty array, but i got Warning from WebStorm like this: 'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'value'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setMyValue' needs the current value of 'value', you can also switch to useReducer ins
tead of useState and read 'value' in the reducer  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps'. Well. when i do how the warning said, app doesn't work as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why do you need this. Shouldn't `my_value` value be based on the updated `value`? but anyway, you can do this:

```
const Counter = ({increase = f => f, decrease = f => f, value = 0}) => {
  const[my_value]  = useState(extraFunc(value));

  return (
      <div>
          <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
          <span style={{padding: "10px"}}>{my_value}</span>
          <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
      </div>
  )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect`, however assigning to `my_value` and then passing to the render as `{my_value}` is problematic. I will strongly recommend using a state variable for that too.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const Counter = ({increase = f => f, decrease = f => f, value = 0}) => {
 
    const [myVal, setMyVal] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
      const my_val = extraFunc(5)
      setMyVal(my_val)
    }, [] /* Empty array makes this useEffect run once only */)

    // Alternative
    useEffect(() => {
      const my_val = extraFunc(value)
      setMyVal(my_val)
    }, [value] /* This will run every time the prop value changes */)
 

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
            <span style={{padding: "10px"}}>{myVal}</span>
            <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: When i use empty dependency array in useEffect, WebStorm always shows me message like this: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'value'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. When i do how the warning said, app doesn't work as i expected. So, what's the matter?

Comment: If you are using `value` inside the useEffect, then it is a dependency. If the app doesn't work as expected after including that , then I would guess it is probably a design mistake, and you should re-evaluate how you manage your app. Because, if value doesn't change the useEffect won't run anyway, and if it changes, you would want to run the useEffect since you want to use the updated value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` Hook for this, by passing an empty array `[]` as second argument.
Note: The counter will increase/decrease but Its value won't be displayed, because it is based on `extraFunc` which is executed only once.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const ProfilerCheckerApp = () => {
    const [counterValue, setCounterValue] = useState(0);
 
    const increase = () => setCounterValue(counterValue + 1);
    const decrease = () => setCounterValue(counterValue - 1);
     
    return (
        <div>
            <Counter increase={increase} decrease={decrease} value={counterValue}/>
        </div>
    )
}
 
const extraFunc = (value) => {
    console.log("ex func works");
    return "value is: " + value;
}
 
const Counter = ({increase = f => f, decrease = f => f, value = 0}) => {
      const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState("");
      useEffect(()=>{
         setMyValue(extraFunc(value));
      }, []); 
     
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
            <span style={{padding: "10px"}}>{myValue}</span>
            <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<ProfilerCheckerApp/>, document.getElementById("main"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-YMtLFKDKe5a4zi7rJ0y4wdGErKZe3tx7L+AXDTxjNDzkv7jsaNhvumeU1xQvw6UqVwBVmYlO9NhsSuSVPUN/xQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0-alpha-bc4e75112-20210815/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-DMCGkVCF04hYYSO4X1mQhMfjdiilNTja3T/NnK02Zs/hsc/jpfnYQ/+Ura375lTzlKrI1z9eoe2X+W4P3pmbGg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: @AlexKor5 You can ping me if you have any issue.

Comment: So, i was trying to use useEffect with empty dependency array [], but right after that action, WebStorm console always shows me message like this:  `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'value'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setMyValue' needs the current value of 'value', you can also switch to useReducer instead of useState and read 'value' in the reducer  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`